# Set recipient address and name for shipping

Tags: android, paypal

I trying to integrate PayPal to my Android app.
I am testing it with Sandbox now.
In my code:
    `pp.setShippingEnabled(true);`
As I understand, recipient address and full name is taken from PayPal account? How can I set this information from my app? Or is it impossible?
Sorry for my English:-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what SDK you're using but it would just a matter of adjusting your API request accordingly.  If you want to gather your customer's address you can then send that with your request over to PayPal and that's what would be used (as long as you set shippingoverride to true.)

I could help you more if I knew what API's you were actually using, and if you want to post a sample of your API request I can help you adjust it to suit your needs.

Comment: I am using MPL and only API methods. As I understand, all requests sent from API PayPalActivity, that is unattainable for the developer.

Comment: Any good SDK would give you easy access to the raw API requests and responses.  That's a very important piece of data for troubleshooting.  If you're using MPL that would make use of the Adaptive Payments API, so your app is mostly likely making calls to the Pay API.  Again, you should have easy access to see these calls.

Comment: In order to get shipping details included with a Pay request, though, you have to include an additional call to SetPaymentOptions.  The SDK you're using may not provide that within the function you're currently using, but one way or another you'll need to get that call included so that you can include things like order item details, shipping address, tax info, etc.